# WCF discard duplicate data

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm writing a gateway between 2 services, one of the services is a very slow webservice, and gets overloaded quickly, the other is super quick and frequently sends the same data.

I'd like to have my service discard (at the earliest point possible) data that I've received that is equal to previous objects.

What is the best way to do this?

The best way I know (which I doubt is best) is to compare received objects after deserialization with the set of objects I've already received (a cache, in other words).

I care more that I discard as much as is computationally easy to discard, than making sure I discard all duplicate data.

FYI, the data has, among other things, geolocational information that is frequently the same.

Clarification:

Situation:

Service 1 is fast and frequently sends updates that have no new data.
Service 2 is slow

I want to send data from Service 1 to Service 2 (with some slight modifications), but only if I haven't already sent the same data.

Dale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say what the best way is without a little more info, but it sounds like you could benefit from a relatively simple cache.  I'm not sure if you're in a write heavy or read heavy scenario, but you should be able to make it work either way.

IE, the quick service is called and checks for results in cache before calling the slow service.

Comment: That's about what I have now, I was hoping there'd be a pre-deserialization or an at deserialization time way to nicely check if it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think Kennith provided a good idea.

Just to frame the problem, it sounds to me like you have something like this situation (clarify your question if this isn't correct)...

[Service 1] -> (Calls) -> [Service 2]

- Service 1 - Faster and overloads Service 2.
- Service 1 - Sends repeat data to Service 2, so much of it can be ignored.

If this is the case, as Kenneth suggested, you may want to implement a caching mechanism of requests that have already been sent from Service 1, and store the answers as received from Service 2. So, in pseudocode, something like this:

1. Service 1 checks in some common storage to see if a request it is about to send has already been sent.
2. If it has, it checks to see the answer that was sent back from Service 2.
3. If it hasn't, it sends the request and adds that request to the list of requests that are sent.
4. When the answer is provided, that is stored in the cache along with the original request.

This will also have the benefit of making your lookups faster via Service 1.

Comment: This isn't exactly my situation, but it's close though -- Service 1 doesn't care about the results from Service 2. I can do (have done) the cache of past data, but I'm doing this cache-checking after the object has been deserialized already, I was hoping there'd be a nice way to do it earlier.

Comment: @user788402 - Ah, okay. Well, if Service 1 doesn't care about the results from Service 2, then you can just cache the fact that you sent the request. You could also include a timestamp on the cached items (with periodic cleanout) so if a duplicate request is sent far later, you can actually send the request through to Service 2 again.

Answer (score 0):

The earliest point possible is to detect the duplicate data is in the sender of the data, not in the receiver.

Add a memory cache there. If the object is duplicate, then no need to serialize it and waste any time sending it.

By the way, if you want a good .Net memory cache, I've had good luck with [Couchbase's](http://www.couchbase.org/get) MemcacheD

Comment: I don't have access to the sender's code -- I'm using 2 third-party services, pushing data from one to the other.